# load page while changing tab

Tags: jquery, css

I am using tabs which are working through css. I need to make tabs which reload the page while changing it. For example if i click on tab 2 it will load/refresh page and active the tab 2.

Here is my html:

```
<main>

  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" >
  <label for="tab1"><img src="img/india_640.png" width="30">INDIA</label>

  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab2"><img src="img/Flag_of_Australia.png" width="30">AUSTRALIA</label>


  <section id="content1">
 content 1
  </section>

  <section id="content2">

Content 2

  </section>

</main>
```

and here is the css:

```
.tabs-origin main {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

.tabs-origin section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs-origin input {
  display: none;
}

.tabs-origin label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.tabs-origin label:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/*
.tabs-origin label[for*='1']:before { content: '\f1cb'; }
.tabs-origin label[for*='2']:before { content: '\f17d'; }
.tabs-origin label[for*='3']:before { content: '\f16b'; }
.tabs-origin label[for*='4']:before { content: '\f1a9'; }
*/

.tabs-origin label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs-origin input:checked + label {
  color: #555;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 2px solid #EA4C88;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;

}

.tabs-origin  #tab1:checked ~ #content1,
.tabs-origin  #tab2:checked ~ #content2,
.tabs-origin  #tab3:checked ~ #content3,
.tabs-origin  #tab4:checked ~ #content4 {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
.tabs-origin   label {
    font-size: 0;
  }
.tabs-origin   label:before {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
.tabs-origin   label {
    padding: 15px;
  }
}
```

You can find this tab working : http://baby-nameo.com/australia.php

Thanks

Comment: If you're going to reload the page when changing tabs, why not just make the tabs into links? `<a href="australia.php"><label for="tab2"><img src="img/Flag_of_Australia.png" width="30">AUSTRALIA</label></a>`

Comment: we are already on australia.php so why it will load the page. it is not working

Comment: Think!! What happens if you're on the _india_ page and do this? What happens if you're on the australia page and click the _india_ tab/link?  :facepalm: When I do links-as-tabs I exclude the link for the _current_ tab anyway, since it's pointless. And — "it is not working" — both here and on Nitish' answer is not informative. You ***must*** provide detail if you want answers instead of guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to the particular `<input>` tag.

```
<input id="tab1" type="radio" onClick="history.go(0)" name="tabs" >
```

This will refresh the page whenever you click on that `input` field.

Comment: Thanks for answer nitish but it is not working as i need.